# How to match SketchUp Camera in Processing/OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, 3d, processing, perspectivecamera

I'm trying to match a scene from Sketchup in Processing/OpenGL but can't seem to get the measurements right.

I'm using these simply commands in the Ruby Console in Sketchup:

```
model = Sketchup.active_model 
cam = model.active_view.camera 
print cam.eye, cam.direction, cam.fov
```

Which prints these values for my file:

```
(1668.854717mm, -1723.414322mm, 131.550996mm)(-0.688802494154077, 0.649067164730165, 0.322897723306109)63.6653435710446nil
```

The FOV seems to work, but I don't think I've figured out the camera position(units) yet.
Here's my attempt:

```
float eyeScale = 1.0f;
float camEyeX = 1668.854717f * eyeScale;
float camEyeY = -1723.414322f * eyeScale;
float camEyeZ = 131.550996f * eyeScale;
float camTargetX = -0.688802494154077f;
float camTargetY = 0.649067164730165f;
float camTargetZ = 0.322897723306109f;
float camFOV = 63.665f;

float div = 10;

void setup(){
    size(1280,720,P3D);
}

void draw(){
    background(255);
    perspective(radians(camFOV), width/height, camEyeZ * 0.1f, camEyeZ * 10);
    camera(camEyeX/div, camEyeY/div, camEyeZ/div, camTargetX, camTargetY, camTargetZ, 1, 0, 0);

    drawGrid(20,10,10,0);
    drawGrid(20,10,10,1);
    drawGrid(20,10,10,2);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) div++;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) div--;
}

void drawGrid(int size,int w,int h,int plane){
    pushStyle();
    noFill();

    if(plane == 0) stroke(255,0,0);
    if(plane == 1) stroke(0,255,0);
    if(plane == 2) stroke(0,0,255);

    int total = w * h;
    int tw = w * size;
    int th = h * size;

    beginShape(LINES);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < total; i++){
        int x = (i % w) * size;
        int y = (i / w) * size;

        if(plane == 0){
             vertex(0,x,0);vertex(0,x,th);
             vertex(0,0,y);vertex(0,tw,y);
        }

        if(plane == 1){
             vertex(x,0,0);vertex(x,0,th);
             vertex(0,0,y);vertex(tw,0,y);
        }

        if(plane == 2){
             vertex(x,0,0);vertex(x,th,0);
             vertex(0,y,0);vertex(tw,y,0);
        }
    }
    endShape();
    popStyle();
}
```

The grids look ok above using the [perspective()](https://processing.org/reference/perspective_.html) call, but if I comment back the [camera()](https://processing.org/reference/camera_.html) call the scene disappears.

Any hints or tips will help. Processing code is ok, but I don't mind raw GL calls/matrices either.

**Update**
Based on @Majlik's notes it's good to point out the differences between the sketchup camera api and Processing's camera api, and on top of that difference in coordinate systems (Sketchup uses Z up, while Processing uses Y up).

I've tried playing with the coordinate system a bit using keys, but I'm not understanding the conversion from Sketchup to Processing/OpenGL:

```
float eyeScale = 1.0f;
float camEyeX = 1668.854717f * eyeScale;
float camEyeY = -1723.414322f * eyeScale;
float camEyeZ = 131.550996f * eyeScale;
float camTargetX = -0.688802494154077f;
float camTargetY = 0.649067164730165f;
float camTargetZ = 0.322897723306109f;
float camFOV = 63.665f;

float div = 10;
PImage bg;
int axis = 0;
boolean flipAxis = false;

void setup(){
    size(1280,720,P3D);
    bg = loadImage("SketchupCam.png");
}

void draw(){
    background(bg);
    perspective(radians(camFOV), width/height, camEyeZ * 0.1f, camEyeZ * 10);
    camera(camEyeX/div, camEyeY/div, camEyeZ/div, 
           camTargetX+camEyeX/div, camTargetY+camEyeY/div, camTargetZ+camEyeZ/div, 
           axis == 0 ? (flipAxis ? -1 : 1) : 0,
           axis == 1 ? (flipAxis ? -1 : 1) : 0,
           axis == 2 ? (flipAxis ? -1 : 1) : 0);

    drawGrid(20,10,10,0);
    drawGrid(20,10,10,1);
    drawGrid(20,10,10,2);
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) div++;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) div--;
  println(div);

  if(key == 'x') axis = 0;
  if(key == 'y') axis = 1;
  if(key == 'z') axis = 2;
  if(key == ' ') flipAxis = !flipAxis;
}

void drawGrid(int size,int w,int h,int plane){
    pushStyle();
    noFill();

    if(plane == 0) stroke(255,0,0);
    if(plane == 1) stroke(0,255,0);
    if(plane == 2) stroke(0,0,255);

    int total = w * h;
    int tw = w * size;
    int th = h * size;

    beginShape(LINES);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < total; i++){
        int x = (i % w) * size;
        int y = (i / w) * size;

        if(plane == 0){
             vertex(0,x,0);vertex(0,x,th);
             vertex(0,0,y);vertex(0,tw,y);
        }
        if(plane == 1){
             vertex(x,0,0);vertex(x,0,th);
             vertex(0,0,y);vertex(tw,0,y);
        }
        if(plane == 2){
             vertex(x,0,0);vertex(x,th,0);
             vertex(0,y,0);vertex(tw,y,0);
        }
    }
    endShape();
    popStyle();
}
```

And here is a Sketchup screenshot I'm trying to match in Processing:
[image: Sketchup Screenshot]

The smaller box is 1000mm in Sketchup.

How I could match the view from Sketchup in Processing/OpenGL ?

Comment: It looks like that FOV is in degrees but in Processing is used radians. Other values are based on same position system so it should be same (just different scale). If it works with opted camera call it uses default values camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0) so maybe you are just looking the other way == maybe different order of axis between SketsUp and Processing?

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm using the radians function above to convert the FOV. The default camera call you're mentioning doesn't seem to make a difference (if I use the camera call only when the mouse is pressed for example, the scene doesn't look any different when the mouse is released). You might be right about the looking direction. I'll have another play

Comment: I couldn't run your sketch correctly because I don't know values of `offset` so just write some basic tips ... now after second look you are using `cam.direction` vector from SketchUp as reference point to look at in Processing so you should apply this vector on camera position and not just pass it as coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `offset`. I've updated the code as plain Processing. I read your previous message again and I'll also need to account for the different order of axis (Processing uses Y up while Sketchup uses Z up). On your current comment, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by applying the cam.direction vector on camera position and not passed as coordinates. Thank you

Comment: I just wanted point out that SketchUp use cam.direction as vector and thus you should define camera.centerX = camEyeX + camTargetX etc for Y and Z parts of coordinates for the [center of the scene](https://processing.org/reference/camera_.html) because Processing define that camera is looking at some point.